# About docker redirect

Tags: docker

## save docker output to host

`docker run centos cat /etc/hosts > asdf`

asdf is saved in my host linux

## save docker output to container

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf '
docker run centos cat /tmp/asdf
cat: /tmp/asdf: No such file or directory
```

It does not work, how can I do it?

## < in container:

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat < /etc/hosts'
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

OK

## < host file

```
docker run centos cat < /etc/hosts
```

nothing happens, how can I cat a host file in container?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> docker run centos sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf '
> docker run centos cat /tmp/asdf
> cat: /tmp/asdf: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> It does not work, how can I do it?

The redirect does work, but after the successful `cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf` the container stops. Then you run a second, separate container, which has no access to the `/tmp/asdf` file created in the first one.

The only thing in common between these two containers is that they were run from the same image `centos`, but they have different IDs and different namespaces.

You need to run the container preventing its main process from stopping (`-d`) and then execute the commands inside the container referring to its name:

```
docker run -d -it --name mycentos centos /bin/sh
docker exec mycentos sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf'
docker exec mycentos cat /tmp/asdf
```

Alternatively, and more akin to real-life scenarios, you should save the file to a data volume. And then ephemeral containers would access the common data.

---

> ```
> docker run centos cat < /etc/hosts
> ```
>
> nothing happens, how can I cat a host file in container?

```
(docker run -i centos cat) < /etc/hosts
```

```
cat /etc/hosts | docker run -i centos cat
```